# How to push to associative array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know this question was asked many times but i cant get it to work properly as i need.
In a node.js ws i push objects into some array like this:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({"name": "someName", "id": 12345});
```

and at the end i send it as a json in the response. 
How can i push into the array so ill be able to extract data like this ( in the client side ):
** the ID numbers are unique

```
var name = dataArr[12345];  //will return 'someName'
```

Im trying to avoid the need to iterate the whole array to get specific values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want named properties, don't use an Array. Arrays are for *ordered* data structures accessed by index.

Use an Object instead.

```
var obj = {};
obj['12345'] = "someName";
```

Comment: How can i add DYNAMIC values to this? lets say i dont know the values - Im pulling them from a database. For ex: obj['DYNAMIC'] = value;

Comment: @user4440845 — Exactly the same way as you use a dynamic variable anywhere. You replace the string literal with a variable containing a string.

Comment: I asked that silly question because i had some exception im my code. It works like a charm now. Thank you!